# Installing Leap Motion sdk into Enthought SDK

Tags: python, python-2.7, enthought, leap-motion

I am trying to install the leap motion sdk into Enthought Canapy. The page called Hello World on leap motion mentions i need to put these four files:

Sample.py, Leap.py, LeapPython.so and libLeap.dylib

into my "current directory". I don't know how to find my current directory. I have tried several things including typing into terminal "python Sample.py" which tells me:

/Users/myname/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'Sample.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

I've tried to put the 4 files in the MacOS file, but it still gives me this error. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

From [Canopy User Guide - "Change directory"](http://docs.enthought.com/canopy/quick-start/code_editor.html#change-directory):

> If you right-click in the Python shell, you will see a command to change the current directory to match the location of the current file in the Code Editor; this uses IPythons magic cd command. For example, this can be convenient when running a demo program which assumes that its data files are in the current directory.

Also, since Canopy's python shell *is* IPython qtconsole, the `%pwd` (print working directory) and `%cd` (change directory) magic commands work there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Put the four files into one folder.
Right click on the Sample.py until it says "Open with" and gives some choices.
Select Python Launcher.app (2.7.6) # This version of Python Launcher must match the Mac built in Python Version.
If your version of LeapPython.so is constructed correctly, it should run.